# Cannot Generate PDF from MySQL Query Using TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, tcpdf

I am 3 days old to PHP programming. I've been able to echo out the while-loop of the code below using PHP, but somehow cannot get it to work when trying to output it on a PDF file using TCPDF.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
//Start building PDF
require_once('.../tcpdf.php');

//Create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF();

//Set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('Arial');

//Add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

//Database parameter
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "testdb";

//connection to database
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT macid, macstatus FROM machid");

//Print query result
$tbl = '<table width="600px" border="1px">';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $macid = $row["macid"];
    $macstatus = $row["macstatus"];

    $tbl .= '<tr><td>' . $macid . '</td><td>' . $macstatus . '<br></td><t/r>';
    }

$tbl .= '</table>';

//Print query result
$pdf->WriteHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('pdftest.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

Comment: There is a typo in the closing <t/r> tag, should be </tr>. That could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider, seeing the HTTP protocol (it may be usefull)
the see : http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

and finaly add to your code

```
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment filename=myfilename.pdf");
```

So In the answer headers, please see network section in Firefox (CTRL+MAJ+Q),

hopes this may help you seeing what's wrong, mostly a silenced  error from the webserver